Selecting Single Row with Lightning Datatable
I’m building an extended lighting datatable, I’m required to allow the users to select one account at a time, and default the first table row to be checked.
I cannot use max-row-selection because we don’t want to have radio buttons.
This is what I’ve tried:
HTML
‹c-extended-lightning-datatable 
key-field="key" 
data={pageData} 
columns={columns} 
onrowselection={handleRowAction}>
</c-extended-lightning-datatable>

JavaScript:
handleRowAction(event) {
        this.selectedRows = [];
        let selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows;
        let element = this.template.querySelector('c-extended-lightning-datatable');

//if user selects the select all checkbox, set selectedRows to empty
        if (event.detail.config.action === 'selectAllRows') {
            selectedRows = element.selectedRows = [];
        } 
     if(selectedRows.length > 1) {
      selectedRows= element.selectedRows= element.selectedRows.slice(1);
      this.selectedRow = selectedRows;
   
      event.preventDefault();       
  } 
}
    

This code works if I strategically go down the rows, but it doesn’t if I randomly select rows.
Any help with this is appreciated. Thank you.

Your code only happens to work when you click "in order" because slice's first parameter is zero-indexed, not one-indexed; selectedRows always returns values in order of the keys in the data array. Instead, just set the selectedRows property to the new item.
priorSelections = [];
handleRowAction(event) {
  if(event.detail.config.action === 'rowSelect') {
    event.target.selectedRows = [event.detail.config.value];
  } else {
    event.target.selectedRows = [];
  }
}

